# Designing code to handle specific error messages processed by a generic function

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, error-handling

I am a beginner in Python, but I have referred several questions related to individually handling error messages in Python and I've also read best practices of raising exceptions. However, this is more of a design question to handle error messages when a single function is used to process/validate errors.

There are individual functions that make different API calls. To handle the response, all these functions use the following generic function:

```
def print_if_error_and_exit(response, debug, message_override_map=None, exit_on_failure=True):
    if hasattr(response, 'status') and (response.status < 200 or response.status >= 300):
        overriden_message = message_override_map.get(response.status) if message_override_map else None
        if overriden_message:
            error_message = overriden_message
        elif hasattr(response, 'message'):
            error_message = response.message
        else:
            error_message = 'No error message found'

        if exit_on_failure:
            print_error_message('Error (HTTP {0}): {1}'.format(response.status, error_message))
            if debug:
                print_error_message(repr(response))
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            raise ResponseException(error_message)
```

Now, we want to retain this function but also have a capability to provide custom, API-specific human-friendly error messages. One way of doing that would be to call this function with a `dict` that can take HTTP status codes along with corresponding customized messages. However, this might not be the best approach, and I was wondering if there was a better way of achieving this objective.

Comment: The dict is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry to say this is not the pythonic way of doing things. The pythonic way is a lot easier. In fact, i would even hazard a guess that this entire function can be done away with. Please refer to https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html the section about ask for forgiveness instead of permission